# Running ffplay video within a jframe

Tags: java, swing, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I wish to play a video in `JFrame`. I am already using `ffmpeg` in my project. As I wish to keep the project light, I am not willing to use other frameworks like `JMF` or other. I know that I can play video using `ffplay`. But the problem here is `ffplay` opens the video in new window when I try

```
ffplay output.avi
```

I wish to put that video within my JFrame, like a player. How can I do this?

**Request**: 
Please ask for any other clarifications, details, and suggest improvements or comment what you find wrong before downvoting or voting to close the question:). I will change it. I am really new to Java, I tried searching this but could not find any possible solution.

*What I tried?* I couln't find anything related to this, so I don't have any code. I am familiar to how to create frames, and can use `runtime` to ffplay video. But I got no clue how to put that video within my window:(.

All suggestions are welcome if you can suggest me other methods to play the video. But I haven't use any frameworks other than `ffmpeg`. And do not wish to make the application heavier. So it would be more helpful if it can be achieved using `ffplay`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [JMF 2.1.1 - Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html).  If the video types you wish to support are covered by the cross-platform<sup>1</sup> version of the JMF, or you can find an SPI for the format, I'd say use JMF.

1. The 'performance pack' version uses natives which are now very old.  I would not recommend trying to use them.

Comment: `jmf` adds >2 mbs to the project. Is it not possible using ffplay?

Comment: *"Is it not possible using ffplay?"*  No idea.  How much does ffplay add the project?

Comment: ffmpeg package is 10 mb. But I am already using it so it is not adding anything extra.

Comment: Odd comment to make.  The way I figure it, the user user is around 8 MB better off (smaller download) using the core JMF over ffplay.

Comment: No but I am already using ffmpeg to convert images, concatenate audios, then also convert to videos, cut video clips, concatenate them later and other things too. Thats why I said ffmpeg is already being used, thus jmf would be additional.

Comment: You keep using the word 'I' like this app. is only for your personal use & there are no other users.  Is that the case?

Comment: No, I mean I am using ffmpeg to convert images to video on client side, the users aren't even aware of that, they would just be using my app right? Not `ffmpeg`. If the app would have been only for me, I wouldn't think twice about using jmf.

Comment: *"..the users aren't even aware of that,.."*  They might be aware of the extra 8 Meg difference between JMF & ffmpeg. *"they would just be using my app right?"*  ..same difference with JMF.  It comes in it's own (obvious) installer, but for the x-plat version, you can side-step the JMF installer entirely and just include the jars.  You're not laboring under the delusion that ffmpeg comes per-installed on the user's machine (e.g. 'supplied with the OS'), right?

Comment: No, I know I would have to tell them to download that, but jmf too will have to be downloaded. So, I was trying to reduce what they need to download, but looks like now I should use jmf instead of wasting time on this.